# The code runs fine on codeblock but fails to run on SPOJ

Tags: c++

This was my first question on spoj,”test - Life, the Universe, and Everything” and i am highly demotivated towards competitve programming.
This was my code and the link to the question is [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int a[10],i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    { 
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=42)
            cout<<a[i]<<endl;
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is running fine on codeblocks but is giving errors here on spoj.
Please someone help me.

Comment: Why do you think that there are 10 numbers. The length of input is not limited. Fortunately, you do not have to read all the input in before printing it out.

Comment: You will  find few positions in the job market where the job description is "Crap out poorly organized code in a very short space of time." (though I will admit this is what happens sometimes) so don't get too depressed about being highly demotivated towards competitive programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by the user he is solving some spoj problem
just for the benefit of other user below is the requirement

> Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the
>   Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely...
>   rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input
>   after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of
>   one or two digits.

Example

```
Input:
1
2
88
42
99
Output:
1
2
88
```

Below is the code used (C++14) code worked in your online judge

Easiest way is just do this (working in you online judge)
Keep taking input until you see 42 and then break

as suggested one of the user  WhozCraig (please see comment)

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    while(std::cin >> n && n != 42)
        std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 sure I will do that

Comment: @ please do add suggestion even i am a begineer

Answer (score 0):

This is my code hope it helps:

```
int n;
cin>>n;
while (!(n==42))  {
    cout<<n<<"\n";
    cin>>n;

}
```